# Could not see IT and UT coverage in Sonarube

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I could not see IT and UT coverage in Sonarube. Below are my properties files of sonar.

Jenkins ver. 1.631 Sonar ver. 5.1.1 Jacoco ver. 0.7.9 Java ver. 1.8 Maven ver. 3.3.9
Followed below URL-

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/

```
sonar.scm.disabled=true
sonar.projectKey=example-Test
sonar.projectName=example-Test
sonar.projectVersion=$PipelineId
sonar.sources=.
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
project-java.sonar.binaries=target/classes
sonar.genericcoverage.itReportPaths=target/site/jacoco.xml
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/site/jacoco.xml
sonar.jacoco.itReportPath=target/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec
sonar.surefire.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
```

Error Logs-

```
10:20:52.727 WARN  - Cobertura report not found at /Users/sonata-example/.jenkins/jobs/example/jobs/example/jobs/Checking/workspace/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
10:20:52.728 INFO  - Sensor CoberturaSensor (done) | time=1ms
10:20:52.728 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsSensor@11cbfa7b
10:20:52.760 WARN  - Findbugs needs sources to be compiled. Please build project before executing sonar or check the location of compiled classes to make it possible for Findbugs to analyse your project.
10:20:52.760 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsSensor@11cbfa7b (done) | time=32ms
10:20:52.760 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor
10:20:52.761 INFO  - parsing /Users/sonata-example/.jenkins/jobs/example/jobs/example/jobs/Checking/workspace/target/surefire-reports
10:20:52.762 ERROR - Reports path not found or is not a directory: /Users/sonata-example/.jenkins/jobs/example/jobs/example/jobs/Checking/workspace/target/surefire-reports
10:20:52.762 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=2ms
10:20:52.762 INFO  - Sensor WebSensor
10:20:53.458 ERROR - Cannot analyze file /Users/sonata-example/.jenkins/jobs/example/jobs/example/jobs/Checking/workspace/admin/src/main/webapp/modules/clientObject/partials/notification-add.html
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.sonar.plugins.web.checks.sonar.UnsupportedTagsInHtml5Check.isUnsupportedTag(UnsupportedTagsInHtml5Check.java:81) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.web.checks.sonar.UnsupportedTagsInHtml5Check.startElement(UnsupportedTagsInHtml5Check.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.web.visitor.HtmlAstScanner.scanElementTag(HtmlAstScanner.java:118) ~[na:na]
.
.
.
WARN  - Too many duplication references on file admin/target/failsafe-reports/Surefire suite/Surefire test.html for block at line 4595. Keep only the first 100 references.
        10:21:24.516 WARN  - Too many duplication references on file admin/target/failsafe-reports/Surefire suite/Surefire test.html for block at line 2723. Keep only the first 100 references.
        10:21:24.516 WARN  - Too many duplication references on file admin/target/failsafe-reports/Surefire suite/Surefire test.html for block at line 4595. Keep only the first 100 references.
        10:21:24.516 WARN  - Too many duplication references on file admin/target/failsafe-reports/Surefire suite/Surefire test.html for block at line 80. Keep only the first 100 references.
        10:21:24.517 WARN  - Too many duplication references on file admin/target/failsafe-reports/Surefire suite/Surefire test.html for block at line 2768. Keep only the first 100 refere
```

Comment: The current version of SonarQube is 6.4, and the current LTS is 5.6.6. You're going to have a hard time finding support for versions earlier than that.

Comment: You should your SonarQube version and plugins.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I feel my error logs are not because of lower version of SonarQube:)If so please let me know to which version I need to upgrade.